# Can I use the dojo framework in Bottle templates, and if so, how?

Tags: dojo, bottle

I've used the dojo framework in websites with good results, and I'm trying to use it in my bottle templates with no luck.  I'm loading the claro theme and the dojo javascript from the hosted version on google.  None of my dijits are showing up, though.  Am I unable to use external libraries with Bottle, or am I missing something basic?

Comment: Of course you can use any JavaScript library. Can you show some code to us?

Comment: @iurisilvio - Thanks for the comment.  Stupid missing closing tag in HTML!!  Feel stupid for missing that one (but I didn't find it until I started posting my code).  Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use external libraries with Bottle.  Check your HTML if you have problems.  If you're missing a closing tag, for example, things don't work as expected.